# Unable to add SHA1 into Firebase certificate fingerprint

Tags: android, firebase, google-api

I am working on Android project where I am unable to put my SHA-1 generated code into Certificate fingerprint. It shows the following error

[image]

Comment: If you are using debug SHA1 then try with release SHA1 key

Comment: That looks like an error on the Firebase side. I think, it's nothing to do with your SHA1 fingerprint.

Comment: Thank you everyone . i resolved the problem .  My google api dint had Oauth client id configured. and i edited the google api finaly it working :)

Comment: To configure google api . First go to google api console ==> credentials ==> Oauth concent screen ==> auth client id . Here create a new id and add your project SHA1 fingerint

Comment: I was  facing same problem . I solved by deleting previous app in firebase with same package name.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I faced this problem too.

As I find there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46911399/1729202 there is a limit for SHA-1 sums per Firebase project.

So if your situation is like mine - multiple apps in one Firebase project - try to split that apps between a few Firebase projects.