# adding sha1 in firebase app fails with error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-console-developer

I am migrating my project from Digits to Firebase. In this process, I need to create an app in Firebase and add SHA-1 of the release build. When I trying to add SHA-1, it gives the following error:

An error occurred when attempting to modify an Android certificate fingerprint. Please try again later.

Found the following two similar question here. Both say that there should be an already existing app on Google API project of Firebase with the same SHA-1. I don't have any other app with the same SHA-1.

[Adding sha1 key fails with error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41460017)

[Can android certificate fingerprint sha1 use in firebase and Google Place API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41355678)

Need help to resolve this issue.

Comment: Probably best to file a ticket with the support team here and include details of the project and the SHA1. https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/

Comment: may be you are using two different account. go to google developer console and check the package name.

Comment: thanks @IanBarber for your link. I have used your given link to connect with Google Firebase support team and resolved my issue. I have posted my solution in the post below.

Answer (score 12):

After all research and conversation with google firebase support team, I found that a firebase project has a max limit on the SHA-1 it can store. In my case, I already had 30+ SHA-1 and I hit the limit. The limit is not well defined as said by Firebase support team. However, it is somewhere around 30+. I have more than 50 apps and I was trying to use only one firebase project as they all share the same user system in our backend. However, after knowing the limit of Google Firebase, I have used 4 different firebase projects to add 50+ Android and iOS apps from Digits to Firebase. My all apps are live and working well now.

Answer (score 1):

**Update Date : 08 Fab 2022**

I too got the same problem and found a solution that If you want to add new SHA1 key in your firebase app then you have to delete one of the previously added SHA1 key.

This solution worked for me